# Disk storage full

Tags: partitioning, disk-usage

First of all, I am a complete beginner to Ubuntu. I was trying to follow along the Ubuntu dual boot installation section from Odin project. According to the guide, I allocated two partitions, the root partition to mount the systems files, and /Home partition to house apps & personal files.

After installing the Chrome browser, Ubuntu notified that the disk storage is almost full. I checked the disk usage analyzer and it showed that there is only 558.2 MB on /Home.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           1.6G  2.1M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda6        15G   14G  161M  99% /
tmpfs           7.8G   89M  7.7G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda7        22G  565M   20G   3% /home
/dev/sda1        96M   35M   62M  37% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G  120K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb4       321G   54G  267G  17% /media/wizcat/Data
```

You can see there there is around 20-22 GB available on /home. Please help me how to tackle this issue as I only have little knowledge so far working around Linux environment.

Comment: As the answer below says, the issue is with / and not /home  You can allocate space from /home to / in a live usb session using eg gparted, but it’s not completely straightforward, and you might be better off reinstalling with more space allocated to /

Comment: A full `/` (root) and and empty `/home` are classic symptoms of new-user-followed-the-wrong-guide. Simply following the sane, sensible Ubuntu Desktop installer default settings would have worked better for you. They were designed with exactly your use case in mind.

Comment: You have two options: 1) You can manually edit your partitions (harder), or 2) You can simply reinstall, wiping and replacing your old partitions (easier). Both are well-documented. Backup all data that you wish to keep before doing either.

Comment: The recommended minimum disk size for a Ubuntu Desktop system of 17.10 & later is 25GB, as most users add software to their system which requires space (on /). Further come *release-upgrade* time loads of free space is required, which is why 25GB is the minimum suggested. I personally like 32GB as I like adding lots of software, but your use of 15GB left *limited little* space for adding software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root partition /dev/sda6 is what's full.  Your /HOME partition is not your problem.

You will need to delete files from somewhere in the root partition to free up more space to silence the warning message.  As a practical matter, 15G is totally insufficient to run a reasonable Ubuntu installation.  You need to create a much larger partition for Ubuntu on your dual boot machine (or install a much larger drive).

Comment: Useful reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements. Minimum recommended storage is 25GB.